# Making table content horizontal MAUI

Tags: .net, tableview, maui, horizontal-scrolling

How to make this table content of tableview horizonatal?

[image]

How to make this table content of tableview horizonatal?

Comment: You can’t.  You could try using a horizontal StackLayout or grid to achieve a similar effect

Comment: Stop posting pictures, instead of code. It is more difficult for us to help you, and the search engines are not that great, to look for the text in your image, should someone decide to ask the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the horizontal table is the same, you can use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve this.

If the content of the horizontal table is different, you can use `Grid` or  `StackLayout` to achieve this just as Jason mentioned.

For example:

```
   <ScrollView> 
    <HorizontalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="10"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <TableView  x:Name="table1"/>

        <TableView  x:Name="table2"/>
        
        <TableView  x:Name="table3"/>

    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```